# Cross Browser Compatibility problem among IE8 and MOzilla firefox

Tags: css, browser, internet-explorer-8

[image]

[image]

I uploaded to images posted above, first showing the output of Firefox ' and second showing IE8's output.
My CSS is looking like this

```
.popBox {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 52%;

    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: #cccccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px/50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px/50px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
span {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: sans-serif;
}
```

I want to achieve the same as shown in FF on IE8.

any help would be highly appreciated.

P.S - I am not well versed on HTML/CSS part ..CSS shown above is embedded in a JSP page. 
but it seems that i am stuck on it today.

[EDIT]

i tried to add something like this 
    -ms-border-radius: 50px|50%;
and i am following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974085%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

and when i reload the page , nothing happens !!
forget the ellipse shape , can't i show any element on mouse over using IE8.

Here is my complete jsp page.

```
    <script>
      function showBox(text, obj) {
            helpNode = document.createElement('div');
            helpNode.id = 'popBox';
            helpNode.setAttribute('class','popBox');
            helpNode.innerHTML = text;
            obj.appendChild(helpNode);
     }

     function hideBox() {
           node = document.getElementById('popBox');
           node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    } 
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.popBox {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 52%;

    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: #cccccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px/50px;


    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px/50px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
span {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: sans-serif;
}
</style>

<c:if test="${sessionScope.helpPurpose != null && sessionScope.helpPurpose != ''}" >
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="15%">
<tr>

<td>
<div onmouseover="showBox('<table  ><tr><td><b>Purpose:       </b><%=request.getSession().getAttribute("helpPurpose") %></td><br> <br><br></table>', this)" onmouseout="hideBox()"><span><img  id="imgperName"  src="<c:url value='/images   /strutsmenu/plus.png'/>" ></span></div>
</td>
<td>
<div><span><font size="2"> Purpose Of Form</font></span></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `border-radius` isn't implemented natively in version of ie prior to ie9.

To use this feature in ie, I suggest looking at the following JavaScript library:  http://css3pie.com/.

Comment: +1. This is exactly what I was about to say. You can't get `border-radius` feature working in IE8 or earlier without some kind of hack, and the Css3Pie library is by far the best hack available for this.